# Wrap an HTML tag in another using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/62w8f00o/

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/4pB78ee.png"/></div>
```

and I want to wrap the `img` tag with an `a` tag using jQuery, like this:

```
$(function() {
  var a = '<a href="http://i.imgur.com/4pB78ee.png"></a>';
  // want to wrap the <img> with the above <a> here
});
```

The final result would be like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/4pB78ee.png">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/4pB78ee.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

How can I wrap my `img` with the `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery wrap function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
$( "img" ).wrap( "<a href=\"http://i.imgur.com/4pB78ee.png\"></a>" );
```

Replace the `$( "img" )` above for the actual selector, you don't want to select all images in your webpage.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5c5bffh1/

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is:

```
$('.inner').wrap('<a class="outer"></a>);
```

So it would be something like:

```
$('img').wrap('<a href="http://i.imgur.com/4pB78ee.png"></a>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuerys .wrap()

```
$(function() {
  var a = '<a href="http://i.imgur.com/4pB78ee.png"></a>';
  $('img').wrap(a);  
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/62w8f00o/1/